# Duplicating Items in list based on value of a different list

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
list2 = [1, 3, 2]
```

desired result:

```
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name2', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name3']
```

Looking to duplicate items in a list based on the corresponding element position of a different list. Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) + [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
list1 = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
list2 = [1, 3, 2]

res = [e1 for e1, e2 in zip(list1, list2) for _ in range(e2)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name2', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name3']
```

Comment: I don't know. I upvoted it, because it's exactly what I needed. *shrug

Answer (score 0):

With `chain` and `repeat` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
res = list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, list1, list2)))
```

Short version:

```
res = [*chain(*map(repeat, list1, list2))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU@9CsIwEN7zFLc1lVBou7g4ufsCpUiMJw3kj@Qc9OVrE62g6HQf9/3dhRtN3vXbEOf5Er0FTRjJe5NA2@AjQcSAkgSoSWrHikZ5Y1CR9u6t2vurW5yMGZ2ohR0M1UFabCsBBXQr6KuxaLqsaQX0ArqRsYhpWWSCl6ImFx3zMfJkkFsZ@HpIaXiOrq5rFqJ2tLCpXmOGTcngm/@28aft9QU/a0X8rgP/6mrQoEVHiX8EzPMD)